# Running init script on a Linux instance at launch on Azure

Tags: linux, azure

I'm launching a Linux VM on Azure (e.g. Ubuntu Server) and want to execute my init script at instance launch.

I want to get the same behavior as with [AWS User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

How can I do that without creating my custom VM image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Custom Script For Linux` extension from Microsoft for any scripting post provisioning of the VM.

Documentation can be [found here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/CustomScript).

Answer (score 1):

Under "Custom data" one can add something like: (assuming Ubuntu OS)
[image]

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
sudo apt update -y  #-y means yes to all prompts
sudo apt install apache2 -y
sudo systemctl status apache2
rm /var/www/html/index.html
cat <<EOF >/var/www/html/index.html
 
<html><body><h1> <font color="blue"> <center>Webserver #01<center></font></h1></body></html>
<html><body><h1> <font color="blue"> <center>Welcome to Microsoft Azure Administrator AZ-104 Training Bootcamp !<center></font></h1></body></html>
<style>
.aligncenter {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE-Pls refer my other answer(Custom data) which is a simpler way of doing this.** 
As recommended,option 2 is to use Linux extension:
[image]

Select extension>>Custom script from Linux(by Microsoft)
[image]

[image]

Need to select a .sh file>>we need to upload it into azure storage account
[image]

Make sure the file name is updated in the command:

[image]

There are multiple ways to run a script in linux:
-Sh script-name.sh
-Bash script-name.sh
-Simply run file ie

```
path/script-name.sh
```

If in current directory,

```
./script-name.sh
```

=========================================================================
**Generating a bash script in windows:**

Ref https://www.howtogeek.com/261591/how-to-create-and-run-bash-shell-scripts-on-windows-10/

Windows comes with Linux integration.

1. Open cmd
2. Type ‘bash’
3. This should open linux prompt.
   If not,follow steps here:
   https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/
4. Following this: https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-shell-scripting.html
   i.  **Create a file** using a vi editor(or any other editor).  Name  script file with extension .sh
   ii. Start the script with **#! /bin/sh**
   iii.    Write some code.
   iv. Save the script file as filename.**sh**

NOTE:For **executing** the script within linux type **bash filename.sh**  (**don’t do this for a startup script created,don’t want it to run on current machine**)